# Users and access

Tags: cognito-forms

Can I have completed forms emailed to a particular address to display the entire form via email or will I be required to login and view the form on the website?

I would like to know if I can get all new forms directly to a specified email address. Not my email, but a specified email such as a partner or online ticket system.

Will that "specified email" count as a "user" or are users only those who sign in and manage forms?

Answer (score 1):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com/).

You can have the notification email set up to go to any email address. You can also check the option under 'Include' to have your entry details be sent out in the notification email. You can learn more about setting this up in our [Help Content](https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/20/building-forms/notification-emails).